# Kotlin companion object unexpected result

Tags: kotlin, companion-object

```
sealed class Color () {
    sealed class Dark (): Color() {
    object DarkRed : Dark()
    object DarkBlue : Dark()
    }   
    override fun toString(): String = when (this) {
        is Color.Dark -> "Dark"
        is Color.Dark.DarkRed -> "Dark Red"
        is Color.Dark.DarkBlue -> "Dark Blue"
    }
    companion object Companion {
    fun make(name: String): Color = when (name) {
        "DarkRed" -> Color.Dark.DarkRed 
        "DarkBlue" -> Color.Dark.DarkBlue
        else -> throw Exception ("Error unkown color '$name'") 
    }
    }
}
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val color = Color.Companion.make("DarkRed")
    println (color.toString()) // Dark is printed not "Dark Red"
}
```

The code above prints *Dark* while I expected *Dark Red*. It seems that the *make* returned type *Color.Dark.DarkRed* is interpreted as *Color.Dark* by the *ofString()* function, why ?

Comment: Because `Dark.DarkRed` is indeed `Color.Dark`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put line `is Color.Dark -> "Dark"` in the end of toString function. In your case `is Color.Dark` returns true for DarkRed.

Answer (score 3):

Because 'DarkRed' is *both* `Dark` and `DarkRed`, and `is Dark` is checked before `is DarkRed`.

`when` will enter the first clause that resolves to true.

To fix this put the most specific checks before the lesser specific checks.